# Salt: Activate virtual environment on salt minion

Tags: python, django, salt-stack

I have some questions about saltstack.

I'm trying to deploy my Django project with saltstack and made that minion install required packages with pip by setting it's `bin_env`. (django lib, etc...)

But when I run a command (`python manage.py` something) It says there's no django and to activate virtual environment.

I read salt docs about venv module(state) but the only thing in there was creating venv.

How can I activate the minion's venv?

thank you.

Comment: as a sidenote, remember that the django webserver is not meant for production, and it's not as secure as a proper webserver + WSGI wrapper.

Comment: @AlbertoChiusole I'm using gunicorn and nginx. :)

Comment: Then you shouldn't need to run `python manage.py` at all.

Comment: I just needed to run `collectstatic` and all problems solved. thank you.

Comment: In case you are going to deploy your site to production, I suggest following these advises: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$  source /(directory path you put for bin_env)/bin/activate`

Comment: I tried cmd.run: - name: source /path/to/venv/bin/activate and It returned True before I post this question, but the commands below (ex: python manage.py collectstatic, etc..) said "Cannot import django~ Activate venv!". Did salt really activated minion's venv? I can't check it..

Comment: Not sure how salt does things under the hood, but probably you need a script rather than a single command. 'source $path` in one state, followed by whatever you want to run in another state, won't work because the shell that activated the venv has finished and closed.

Comment: If you're running a single command with e.g. cmd.run, you could do it as one line. `salt $tgt cmd.run "source $path/activate; python manage.py something"`

Comment: thanks Andrew, I defined the venv path as jinja constant and using it like "`. {{venv_path}}; python {{BASEDIR}}/path/to/djangoProj/manage.py command;`" and It works well.

Comment: oh i didnt read your thing,  this `pip.installed` state has a `bin_env` and `requirements` arguments to install all your required packages in the right spot:  https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pip_state.html

Comment: I'm using pip.installed with `bin_env` as you said, I just needed to run django's `collectstatic` for nginx and all problems solved. thank you :)